# Vaadin 7 Spring Security return user to original page after login

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7, Spring Boot application after successful authentication/authorization I need to return user to a page where login process was initiated.

But right now user returns to home page.

For example if user goes to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/vaadin-ui/!#search
```

it redirects him to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/vaadin-ui/login#search
```

and after login process to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/vaadin-ui/
```

How to tell Spring Security and Vaadin application to return user to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/vaadin-ui/!#search
```

url ?

Comment: How are you authenticating/authorising the user, and how did you implement the navigation part?

Comment: For navigation part I'm using demo from https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common  For Spring + Spring Security - vaadin-spring-boot-starter, vaadin-spring-ext-core, vaadin-spring-ext-boot, vaadin-spring-ext-security.. etc